# Html, Ícone respeitando a cor de fundo da pagina

Tags: html, css, img

Eu estou inserindo na minha página uma imagem que tem um evento, essa imagem tem um desenho, e o fundo do desenho é branco, eu gostaria que esse fundo desse desenho fosse preenchido com a mesma cor da página.

A página é de cor cinza, mas o desenho tem um fundo branco, gostaria que tivesse a mesma cor da página, segue o código.

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/img/menuicon.png" />
```

Comment: Acho que a única maneira de fazer isso é só colocando uma imagem que tenha o fundo transparente. Posso estar errado.

Answer (score 0):

Esse caso não tem nada a ver com o HTML - você precisa editar a imagem para que ela tenha um fundo transparente.

Se você tratar a imagem no GIMP, pode abrir o arquivo, ir em `Camada->Adicionar canal alfa`, pegue a ferramenta de seleção por cores (na configuração padrão do GIMO, é a quinta ferramenta na caixa de ferramentas),clique no fundo branco, e vá em `editar->cortar`, e por fim, exporte a imagem resultante. Use essa na sua página.

(A resposta é O.T. no stackoverflow - mas a dúvida aconteceu no âmbito de HTML. Em sites em inglês esse tipo de resposta está no https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Existe uma forma de tornar transparente uma cor específica de uma imagem usando `canvas`. No seu caso, a imagem tem um fundo branco, então, com `canvas`, não apenas o fundo ficaria transparente, mas qualquer parte branca da imagem.

Se achar válido aplicar o script abaixo em seu código (em vez de usar um aplicativo gráfico para retirar o fundo do seu ícone em questão), segue ele:

HTML:

A imagem e o `canvas` devem estar na mesma `div`:

```
<div>
    <img id="fundobranco" src="imagem.png" style="display: none;">
    <canvas id="semfundobranco"></canvas>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    id_imagem = "fundobranco"; // id da imagem
    largura_imagem = 400; // width da imagem
    altura_imagem = 400; // height da imagem

    var canvas = document.getElementById("semfundobranco"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    image = document.getElementById(id_imagem);

    canvas.height = altura_imagem; canvas.width = largura_imagem;
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);

    var imgd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, largura_imagem, altura_imagem),
    pix = imgd.data,
    newColor = {r:0,g:0,b:0, a:0};

    for(var i = 0, n = pix.length; i <n; i += 4){
        var r = pix[i],
        g = pix[i+1],
        b = pix[i+2];
        if(r== 255 && g == 255 && b == 255){ 
            pix[i] = newColor.r;
            pix[i+1] = newColor.g;
            pix[i+2] = newColor.b;
            pix[i+3] = newColor.a;
        }
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imgd, 0, 0);
}
</script>
```

> **Notas:**
>
> 1. A imagem deve estar no mesmo domínio.
> 2. Só funciona em navegadores com suporte ao HTML5 (navegadores mais
>      modernos).

Answer (score -1):

Obrigado pelas respostas gente.
A melhor opção que encontrei foi essa aqui:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Agradeço a ajuda de todos.
Att